# JQuery grid filter menu disappearing behind modal

Tags: jquery, jqxgrid

I have a web page showing a grid. I want to offer the user details about some row in the grid and display the result in a popup (modal) that also contains a grid. Everything looks fine except that the popup filter menu in the grid in the modal disappears behind the modal. To illustrate this I have modified one of jqxgrid demo pages and added a button to show the content in a modal window with exactly the same features.

I included the full page for easy reproduction. You might have to tweak the paths for including "css" and script files. "Demo.js" is - as I have learned - the new version of "generatedata.js".

I have also set the height of the grid in the modal to make visual what is happening.

I hope someone can help me out, either explain that this is not going to work or show some workaround or solution.

Thank you

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title id='Description'>This example illustrates the Grid filtering feature. Move the mouse cursor over a column header and click the dropdown button to open the filtering menu.</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="jqwidgets/styles/jqx.base.css" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jqwidgets/jqxcore.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jqwidgets/jqxdata.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jqwidgets/jqxbuttons.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jqwidgets/jqxscrollbar.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jqwidgets/jqxlistbox.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jqwidgets/jqxdropdownlist.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jqwidgets/jqxmenu.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jqwidgets/jqxgrid.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jqwidgets/jqxgrid.filter.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jqwidgets/jqxgrid.sort.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jqwidgets/jqxgrid.selection.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jqwidgets/jqxpanel.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jqwidgets/jqxcheckbox.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/demos.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="generatedata.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var theme = getDemoTheme();
      var data = generatedata(500);
      var source = {
        localdata: data,
        datafields: [{
            name: 'firstname',
            type: 'string'
          },
          {
            name: 'lastname',
            type: 'string'
          },
          {
            name: 'productname',
            type: 'string'
          },
          {
            name: 'date',
            type: 'date'
          },
          {
            name: 'quantity',
            type: 'number'
          },
          {
            name: 'price',
            type: 'number'
          }
        ],
        datatype: "array"
      };
      var addfilter = function() {
        var filtergroup = new $.jqx.filter();
        var filter_or_operator = 1;
        var filtervalue = 'Beate';
        var filtercondition = 'contains';
        var filter1 = filtergroup.createfilter('stringfilter', filtervalue, filtercondition);
        filtervalue = 'Andrew';
        filtercondition = 'starts_with';
        var filter2 = filtergroup.createfilter('stringfilter', filtervalue, filtercondition);
        filtergroup.addfilter(filter_or_operator, filter1);
        filtergroup.addfilter(filter_or_operator, filter2);
        // add the filters.
        $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('addfilter', 'firstname', filtergroup);
        // apply the filters.
        $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('applyfilters');
      }
      var adapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source);
      $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid({
        width: 670,
        source: adapter,
        theme: theme,
        filterable: true,
        sortable: true,
        ready: function() {
          addfilter();
        },
        autoshowfiltericon: true,
        columns: [{
            text: 'First Name',
            datafield: 'firstname',
            width: 90
          },
          {
            text: 'Last Name',
            datafield: 'lastname',
            width: 90
          },
          {
            text: 'Product',
            datafield: 'productname',
            width: 170
          },
          {
            text: 'Order Date',
            datafield: 'date',
            width: 160,
            cellsformat: 'dd-MMMM-yyyy'
          },
          {
            text: 'Quantity',
            datafield: 'quantity',
            width: 80,
            cellsalign: 'right'
          },
          {
            text: 'Unit Price',
            datafield: 'price',
            cellsalign: 'right',
            cellsformat: 'c2'
          }
        ]
      });
      $('#events').jqxPanel({
        width: 300,
        height: 80,
        theme: theme
      });
      $("#jqxgrid").on("filter", function(event) {
        $("#events").jqxPanel('clearcontent');
        var filterinfo = $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('getfilterinformation');
        var eventData = "Triggered 'filter' event";
        for (i = 0; i < filterinfo.length; i++) {
          var eventData = "Filter Column: " + filterinfo[i].filtercolumntext;
          $('#events').jqxPanel('prepend', '<div style="margin-top: 5px;">' + eventData + '</div>');
        }
      });
      $('#clearfilteringbutton').jqxButton({
        height: 25,
        theme: theme
      });
      $('#filterbackground').jqxCheckBox({
        checked: true,
        height: 25,
        theme: theme
      });
      $('#filtericons').jqxCheckBox({
        checked: false,
        height: 25,
        theme: theme
      });
      // clear the filtering.
      $('#clearfilteringbutton').click(function() {
        $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('clearfilters');
      });
      // show/hide filter background
      $('#filterbackground').on('change', function(event) {
        $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid({
          showfiltercolumnbackground: event.args.checked
        });
      });
      // show/hide filter icons
      $('#filtericons').on('change', function(event) {
        $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid({
          autoshowfiltericon: !event.args.checked
        });
      });
    });

    function viewSubgridModalWithFilter(title) {
      $("#jqxgridModal").remove();
      $("#jqxgridmodalContainer").append('<div id="jqxgridModal" ></div>');
      $("#gridmodalTitle").html(title);
      var theme = getDemoTheme();
      var data = generatedata(500);
      var source = {
        localdata: data,
        datafields: [{
            name: 'firstname',
            type: 'string'
          },
          {
            name: 'lastname',
            type: 'string'
          },
          {
            name: 'productname',
            type: 'string'
          },
          {
            name: 'date',
            type: 'date'
          },
          {
            name: 'quantity',
            type: 'number'
          },
          {
            name: 'price',
            type: 'number'
          }
        ],
        datatype: "array"
      };
      var addfilter = function() {
        var filtergroup = new $.jqx.filter();
        var filter_or_operator = 1;
        var filtervalue = 'Beate';
        var filtercondition = 'contains';
        var filter1 = filtergroup.createfilter('stringfilter', filtervalue, filtercondition);
        filtervalue = 'P';
        filtercondition = 'starts_with';
        var filter2 = filtergroup.createfilter('stringfilter', filtervalue, filtercondition);
        filtergroup.addfilter(filter_or_operator, filter1);
        filtergroup.addfilter(filter_or_operator, filter2);
        // add the filters.
        $("#jqxgridModal").jqxGrid('addfilter', 'firstname', filtergroup);
        // apply the filters.
        $("#jqxgridModal").jqxGrid('applyfilters');
      }
      var adapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source);
      $("#jqxgridModal").jqxGrid({
        width: 670,
        height: 100,
        source: adapter,
        theme: theme,
        filterable: true,
        sortable: true,
        ready: function() {
          addfilter();
        },
        autoshowfiltericon: true,
        columns: [{
            text: 'First Name',
            datafield: 'firstname',
            width: 90
          },
          {
            text: 'Last Name',
            datafield: 'lastname',
            width: 90
          },
          {
            text: 'Product',
            datafield: 'productname',
            width: 170
          },
          {
            text: 'Order Date',
            datafield: 'date',
            width: 160,
            cellsformat: 'dd-MMMM-yyyy'
          },
          {
            text: 'Quantity',
            datafield: 'quantity',
            width: 80,
            cellsalign: 'right'
          },
          {
            text: 'Unit Price',
            datafield: 'price',
            cellsalign: 'right',
            cellsformat: 'c2'
          }
        ]
      });
      $('#eventsM').jqxPanel({
        width: 300,
        height: 80,
        theme: theme
      });
      $("#jqxgridModal").on("filter", function(event) {
        $("#eventsM").jqxPanel('clearcontent');
        var filterinfo = $("#jqxgridModal").jqxGrid('getfilterinformation');
        var eventData = "Triggered 'filter' event";
        for (i = 0; i < filterinfo.length; i++) {
          var eventData = "Filter Column: " + filterinfo[i].filtercolumntext;
          $('#eventsM').jqxPanel('prepend', '<div style="margin-top: 5px;">' + eventData + '</div>');
        }
      });
      $('#clearfilteringbuttonM').jqxButton({
        height: 25,
        theme: theme
      });
      $('#filterbackgroundM').jqxCheckBox({
        checked: true,
        height: 25,
        theme: theme
      });
      $('#filtericonsM').jqxCheckBox({
        checked: false,
        height: 25,
        theme: theme
      });
      // clear the filtering.
      $('#clearfilteringbuttonM').click(function() {
        $("#jqxgridModal").jqxGrid('clearfilters');
      });
      // show/hide filter background
      $('#filterbackgroundM').on('change', function(event) {
        $("#jqxgridModal").jqxGrid({
          showfiltercolumnbackground: event.args.checked
        });
      });
      // show/hide filter icons
      $('#filtericonsM').on('change', function(event) {
        $("#jqxgridModal").jqxGrid({
          autoshowfiltericon: !event.args.checked
        });
      });
      $("#startSubgridModal").modal({
        backdrop: "static"
      });
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body class='default'>
  <div class="modal fade" role="dialog" id="startSubgridModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog" id="subgrid_dialog" style="width:90%;">
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content" style="height=90%;overflow-y:auto">

        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h3 id="gridmodalTitle">Pallets</h3>
        </div>
        <div style="overflow:hidden">
          <div id="jqxgridmodalContainer">
            <div id="jqxgridModal"></div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div id="eventslogM" style="margin-top: 10px;">
          <div style="width: 200px; float: left; margin-right: 10px;">
            <input value="Remove Filter" id="clearfilteringbuttonM" type="button" />
            <div style="margin-top: 10px;" id='filterbackgroundM'>Filter Background</div>
            <div style="margin-top: 10px;" id='filtericonsM'>Show All Filter Icons</div>
          </div>
          <div style="float: left;">
            Event Log:
            <div style="border: none;" id="eventsM">
            </div>
          </div>
          <input id="btnViewModalM" type="button" onclick="viewSubgridModalWithFilter('Grid modal')" value="Show modal" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id='jqxWidget' style="font-size: 13px; font-family: Verdana; float: left;">
    <div id="jqxgrid">
    </div>
    <div id="eventslog" style="margin-top: 30px;">
      <div style="width: 200px; float: left; margin-right: 10px;">
        <input value="Remove Filter" id="clearfilteringbutton" type="button" />
        <div style="margin-top: 10px;" id='filterbackground'>Filter Background</div>
        <div style="margin-top: 10px;" id='filtericons'>Show All Filter Icons</div>
      </div>
      <div style="float: left;">
        Event Log:
        <div style="border: none;" id="events">
        </div>
      </div>
      <input id="btnViewModal" type="button" onclick="viewSubgridModalWithFilter('Grid modal')" value="Show modal" />
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You'd get more help if you had a working demo for people to see.

Comment: @Lee: What a good advice to create a working demo! As it turns out not all versions of jqwidgets show this behavior. I could not find a cdn for the version I was using and created a demo with version 3.8.2 and ... it works fine. Then I used a version 5.7.2 which didn't whereas version 4.5.3 does ok and version 8.1.4 fails also. So I found a version that works for me. That is all I need for now.

Comment: I am sorry but I do not have a website to show the page. A modal does not behave as modal on jsfiddle. Can I put it up somewhere else?